# Vocoder command line tool for Linux or Mac?

Tags: mac, effect, vocoder, linux

Does any Linux or Mac command line tool support vocoder effect?

Answer (score 1):

If by vocoder you mean "voice simulator" you can try the following cli on your Mac's terminal:

> $say "Hello World"

For more informations about the command line type in

> $man say

If you search for the other type of vocoder, try [Jack](http://www.jackaudio.org/) with a normal vst plugin like [Matrix](http://www.virsyn.de/en/E_Products/E_MATRIX/e_matrix.html) on your Mac.

If you are on Linux it's even better here is what I've found searching on google : [vocoder linux jack](http://www.sirlab.de/linux/download_vocoder_standalone_jack.html).

A simple aliasing of your script could create a simple command line for you to call in order to use the vocoder.

Best,